# i am creating checkbox dynamically from a list ,now how to check user selected which checkbox from a list in android

Tags: android, checkbox

i am creating checkbox dynamically from a list ,now how to check user selected which checkbox from a list  in android

```
for (int i = 0; i < languageList.size(); i++) {

    HashMap<String, String> item_hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String lang = languageList.get(i).getLanguage();
    final String langId = languageList.get(i).getLanguageId();
    item_hash.put(langId, lang);

    ar[i] = langId;

    // String langId = languageList.get(i).getLanguage_id();
    item_list1.add(item_hash);
    cb = new CheckBox(parentActivity);
    cb.setText(languageList.get(i).getLanguage().toString());
    cb.setId(Integer.parseInt(languageList.get(i).getLanguageId()));

    Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

    // show location button click event
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(cb.isChecked()){
                  System.out.println("id "+cb.getText()+langId);

            }


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: any help will be appreciated

Comment: You seem to re-use `cb` this way all your checkboxes will be pointing to you last checkbox ...

Comment: yes , i know but how to uniquely identifies every cb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would be better if you should use a ListView. But if you prefer use your way you need and checkbox array

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> cbs = new ArrayList<Checkbox>();
for (int i = 0; i < languageList.size(); i++) 
{

    HashMap<String, String> item_hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String lang = languageList.get(i).getLanguage();
    final String langId = languageList.get(i).getLanguageId();
    item_hash.put(langId, lang);

    ar[i] = langId;

    // String langId = languageList.get(i).getLanguage_id();
    item_list1.add(item_hash);
    cb = new CheckBox(parentActivity);
    cb.setText(languageList.get(i).getLanguage().toString());
      cb.setId(Integer.parseInt(languageList.get(i).getLanguageId()));
    cbs.add(cb);
```

}

```
Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);

// show location button click event
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < languageList.size(); i++)
            if(cbs.get(i).isChecked())
                 System.out.println("id "+cbs.get(i).getText()+langId);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a unique tag to every `CheckBox` and get it inside the CheckListener along with the declaration like the following way:

```
    // at the class declaration define the following static element 
    static int cb_selected;

    // then inside the for loop
    cb.setTag(i);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                cb_selected = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString().trim());
        }
    });
```

And if you want to save all checked `checkboxes`:

```
    // before the for loop
    final List<String> selected = new ArrayList<>();
    // then inside the for loop
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                selected.add(buttonView.getTag().toString().trim());
            else
                selected.remove(buttonView.getTag().toString().trim());
        }
    });
```

So, when trying to see what checked, just look at this `ArrayList`.